# Numpy array and for loop: how to improve it

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, for-loop

I am new with Python and I have a question about a for loop to speed up.

Let "u" be an numpy array of dimension (N,K) and let "kernel_vect" be a numpy array of dimension (K,) both of float64 numbers.
I would like to speed up the following code (by eliminating the for loop for example)

```
Kernel_appo = np.zeros((N**2,))
    for k in range(K):
        uk = u[:,k]
        Mat_appo = np.outer(uk,uk)
        Kernel_appo = Kernel_appo  + kernel_vect[k] * routines.vec(Mat_appo)
```

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: What `routines.vec` is supposed to do? What are typical values for `N` and `K`?

Comment: Ah, sorry! routine.vec stacks the columns of a matrix into an array (column by column). N is small (less than 100), K is bigger of an order of magnitude or more

Comment: Ok. When you say it "stack the columns", it means that for a matrix `[[0, 1], [2, 3]]` (row-major) the result would be `[0, 2, 1, 3]`, isn't it? If not, can you put the code of this function it it is short?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I'm just using this function basically "np.ravel(x, order='F')"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a faster implementation without a loop over k:

```py
# Version 2
Kernel_appo = np.zeros((N**2,))
for n1 in range(N):
    for n2 in range(N):
        Kernel_appo[n1*N+n2] = (u[n1,:] * u[n2,:] * kernel_vect).sum()
```

We can make it faster by using the symmetry of the u product:

```py
# Version 3
Kernel_appo = np.zeros((N,N))
for n1 in range(N):
    for n2 in range(n1,N):
        Kernel_appo[n1,n2] = (u[n1,:] * u[n2,:] * kernel_vect).sum()
Kernel_appo = np.triu(Kernel_appo, 1) + np.tril(Kernel_appo.transpose(), 0) # make the matrix symmetric
Kernel_appo = np.ravel(Kernel_appo, order='C')
```

Here is a version that remove one of the loop:

```py
# Version 4
Kernel_appo = np.zeros((N,N))
for n1 in range(N):
    Kernel_appo[n1,n1:N] = ((u[n1,:] * kernel_vect) * u[n1:N,:]).sum(axis=1)
Kernel_appo = np.triu(Kernel_appo, 1) + np.tril(Kernel_appo.transpose(), 0)
Kernel_appo = np.ravel(Kernel_appo, order='C')
```

We still have a loop over N. However, this seems reasonable to keep it since N is small. Removing it will certainly force numpy to create huge matrices in memory which should cause a performance drop (and can even crash if N and K a very big).

Note that Version 4 will probably not be so fast if K is much bigger (since temporary numpy matrices could not fit in the cache of the CPU).

**UPDATE**: I just discover that this is possible to use the awesome `np.einsum` in this case:

```py
# Version 5
Kernel_appo = np.ravel(np.einsum('ji,ki,i->jk', u, u, kernel_vect, optimize=True), order='C')
```

Be prepared, because this *simpler* implementation is also *much faster* (because numpy is able to vectorize the code and run it in parallel).

Here are performance results with N=50 and K=5000 on my machine:

```
Initial code: 58.15 ms
Version 2:    19.94 ms
Version 3:    10.11 ms
Version 4:     5.08 ms
Version 5:     0.57 ms
```

The final implementation is now about 100 times faster than the initial one!

Comment: Great answer! Just a last point: if in my code, instead of `Mat_appo = np.outer(uk,uk)`, I have `Mat_appo = np.outer(uk,uk.conj)`, how can I change Version 4 to adress complex vectors?

Comment: I do not think `Mat_appo` is symmetric in this case. So you cannot directly use *version 3* and *version 4* (version 2 still work if you add `conj`). Indeed, *version 3* assumes a symmetry and *version 4* is based on it. However, you can start from *version 2*, then add the `conj` call and then apply the *version 3 to 4* modifications (which consists in only working on 2D arrays rather than vectors). This last step can be done by just replacing `u[n1:N,:]` by `u[0:N,:]`, and removing the `triu`/`tril`-based line.

Comment: Ok, thanks! Yes, `Mat_appo` is not symmetric but Hermitian (i.e. `Mat_appo` is equal to `Mat_appo.T.conj`). I'll try to work on it! Thanks again!

Comment: Ok. I did not see that `Mat_appo` was hermitian! Thus, `Kernel_appo` should be too. So, I think you can use the last version and just add a `.conj()` in the vector-matrix product (note that regarding the term on which you put the `.conj()`, you will need a final `.transpose()` on `Kernel_appo`) as well as after the `np.tril(...)` call.